# C++ copying files. Short on data

Tags: c++, file, copy

I'm trying to copy a file, but whatever I try, the copy seems to be a few bytes short.

_file is an ifstream set to binary mode.

```
void FileProcessor::send()
{
    //If no file is opened return
    if(!_file.is_open()) return;
    //Reset position to beginning
    _file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    //Result buffer
    char * buffer;
    char * partBytes = new char[_bufferSize];
    //Packet *p;
    //Read the file and send it over the network

    while(_file.read(partBytes,_bufferSize))
    {
        //buffer = Packet::create(Packet::FILE,std::string(partBytes));
        //p = Packet::create(buffer);
        //cout<< p->getLength() << "\n";
        //writeToFile(p->getData().c_str(),p->getLength());
        writeToFile(partBytes,_bufferSize);
        //delete[] buffer;
    }

    //cout<< *p << "\n";
    delete [] partBytes;
}
```

_writeFile is the file to be written to.

```
void FileProcessor::writeToFile(const char *buffer,unsigned int size)
{
    if(_writeFile.is_open())
    {
        _writeFile.write(buffer,size);
        _writeFile.flush();
    }
}
```

In this case I'm trying to copy a zip file.
But opening both the original and copy in notepad I noticed that while they look identical , It's different at the end where the copy is missing a few bytes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Minor suggestion: Don't start your variable names with `_`, most uses of that are reserved for the compiler or standard library.

Comment: As much as I wish to apply my own convention, It's not up to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that the file's size is a multiple of `_bufferSize`. You have to check what's left on the buffer **after** the while:

```
while(_file.read(partBytes,_bufferSize)) {
  writeToFile(partBytes,_bufferSize);
}
if(_file.gcount())
    writeToFile(partBytes, _file.gcount());
```

Comment: Yes!  I tried this before but for some reason I kept going out of bounds.

But this works =D

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will terminate when it fails to read _bufferSize bytes because it hits an EOF.

The final call to read() might have read some data (just not a full buffer) but your code ignores it.

After your loop you need to check _file.gcount() and if it is not zero, write those remaining bytes out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to always do `writeToFile(partBytes,_bufferSize);` since it's possible (at the end) that less than `_bufferSize` bytes were read. Also, as pointed out in the comments on this answer, the `ifstream` is no longer "true" once the EOF is reached, so the last chunk isn't copied (this is your posted problem). Instead, use `gcount()` to get the number of bytes read:

```
do
{
    _file.read(partBytes, _bufferSize);
    writeToFile(partBytes, (unsigned int)_file.gcount());
} while (_file);
```

For comparisons of zip files, you might want to consider using a non-text editor to do the comparison; [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a great (free) hex editor with a file compare option.

Comment: Interestingly enough the conversion from that method to int does not exist...?
Any ideas?

Comment: @Sidar: Yep, I must have been thinking of a different `read()` function, sorry. I've updated my answer with (hopefully) correct code!

Comment: Also - I believe `istream::read` may return an object which converts to false in case it read less than `_bufferSize` bytes, in which case the body of the `while` will not be executed.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If the last read is partial, `writeToFile` won't be called, so the problem will persist.

Comment: No success. While the code does run, the same results occur.

Eventually the partBytes need to be send off into a Packet to be send over a network. So the writeFile isn't called directly.

Comment: That won't work. After read reaches end of file, the eof bit will be set, and operator void* will return 0, making the while break without writing the bytes left in the buffer.

Comment: @fontanini: Yep, as pointed out by you, user1071136, and Mat, the condition was wrong. I've fixed it now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying from one type of media to another?  Perhaps different sector sizes are causing the apparent weirdness.

What if _bufferSize doesn't divide evenly into the size of the file...that might cause extra bytes to be written.

Comment: At this point it's both writing from the desktop directory.

The funny thing is, I'm short on bytes.